# murray d100-22 main electrical panel bus bar rating (solar?)

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, solar-panels, solar

[image: Label of electrical panel]

Murray d100-22 main electrical panel bus bar rating

It is a 20-slot. The wire coming from PG&E is a 2 AWG Alum wire.
I want to install solar panels. And wondering what is the bus bar rating of the panel.

The main breaker is 100A. If the bus bar is higher than 100 (i.e say 125) then I can install more than 6.4KW for solar, else I would have to go for an upgrade which is not possible as this is an underground utility service.

The label doesn't seem to specify the bus bar, but it does say the line connector range is 8-1/0.

Is there a way to know what the bus bar rating is?

Answer (score 5):

### This is a 100A bussed panel

I can tell that this is a 100A bussed panel because it only has a single rating for both main breaker and busbars, namely 100A.  A panel that could take either 100A or 125A (for instance) breakers on a 125A bus would say so on the label.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cost-cutter "all-in-one" panel. I'm not a fan, because changing *anything* later is expensive.  They're great for builders, because they save installation labor, and nobody ever reduced their offer on a house over an all-in-one.

You were told a **service upgrade** would be required if you wanted to put more than "20A" (3.8 kW) of solar on this panel.  *That is incorrect, unless the power company has a stupid rule to that effect*.

### First option: another all-in-one

You absolutely can change this "all-in-one" to a different all-in-one that is **solar-ready**.  What is that? It's a tap *before the main breaker* that goes to a special breaker space. That's where the solar breaker goes.

How do you get a 100A all-in-one, though?  Easy. When you buy the unit, say "I need that in a 100A main breaker". If they don't have it factory made, they'll sell you a loose 100A main breaker and you swap it in.

Therefore no service upgrade is needed, and the existing underground lines will suffice.  See how that works?  *EVen better, this "solar-ready" approach means **no limit on solar** - you could have 19.2 kW of solar if you want*.

Really, service upgrades are virtually things of the past, due to [technology changes in panels](https://youtu.be/CVLLNjSLJTQ?t=448).  Eaton "BR" and Square D "QO" are hot-beds of this tech, and Eaton in particular is all about being able to retrofit it into existing panels (NOT sell you a new panel like the "SPAN").  Technology Connections talks about SPAN because none of the competitors are ready for prime-time.  But they're working earnestly on it!

I do not recommend having a solar company do this work, because they are universally morons.  Almost every interaction we see reported here involves a *spectacularly unqualified* drone worker actually doing the electrical work, who "phones home" to a licensed electrician who hands out and approves plans from 500 miles away. The mistakes are legendary. Hire a local electrician for the panel swap.

### Second option: a staged approach where you get a new indoor panel

In this scenario, you install a subpanel in your house, fed by a 100A breaker from your main panel.  Move every circuit to it, one at a time and at your leisure.

Once the all-in-one is totally empty (except for the main and the 100A breaker for the sub), you can designate it a "Solar-ONLY" panel and again you have defeated the solar limits.  You can even have multiple solar systems, as long as the solar breakers sum to less than 100A.

A surge suppressor and generator interlock can be in the original all-in-one, since they aren't loads.

### Option #3: Meter adapters

These clever gadgets sit "underneath" the meter, i.e. sandwich between meter pan and meter. They require power company approval, which is why I mention them last. Again, since they tie in on the utility side of the main breaker, they have no amp limit on the solar, and you can run 19.2kW of solar if you want to.

[Here's San Diego's page on them](https://www.sdge.com/residential/savings-center/solar-power-renewable-energy/renewable-meter-adapter).  That particular one has a built in breaker, however that's power company's discretion.